# Convert List<POCO> to Datatable in C#.NET

Tags: c#, orm, datatable, automapper

I am looking for the cleanest way availble to convert a List into a datatable.

I came across some articles which was basically combination of Foreach +Reflection. Not a bad option IF there is no other cleaner way to do it. After some research I came across this article which uses Auto-mapper to hydrate objects from data table:

http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/

I am wondering if exactly opposite is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?

You can find a library that can help: [FastMember](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FastMember/)

Or, you can write something up using reflection.

Comment: Probably same reason I'm looking for something! Use legacy datatable based UI layer with a poco data layer.